# How to use script. in JADE templates

Tags: express, pug

I have created a simple node app using the express framework using JADE templating.

All was well in the learning process until I came to try and run some client-side js which I cannot figure out how to do.

Is there something I need to do in my app/index.js to tell node about them? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**index.jade**

```
 extends layout

 block content

 h1 Title

 script.
   console.log("I am running on the client");
```

**app.js**

```js
 var http = require("http")
 var express = require("express")
 var path = require('path');
 var routes = require('./routes/index');

 var app = express()
 var port = process.env.PORT || 5000

 // view engine setup
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
 app.set('view engine', 'jade');

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 app.use('/', routes);

 var server = http.createServer(app)
 server.listen(port)

 console.log("http server listening on %d", port)

 module.exports = app;
```

**layout.jade**

```
 doctype html
 html
   head
     title= title
     link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
     link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css')
     link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
     script(src='/javascripts/jquery-2.1.3.js') 
     script(src='/javascripts/bootstrap.js') 

   body
     div(class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top")
       .container
         .navbar-header
           button.navbar-toggle(type="button", data-toggle="collapse", data-target=".navbar-collapse")
             span.icon-bar
             span.icon-bar
             span.icon-bar
           a.navbar-brand(href="/") Twitter
         div(class="collapse navbar-collapse")
           ul(class="nav navbar-nav")
             li.active
               a(href="#") Home
             li
               a(href="#about") About
             li
               a(href="#contact") Contact
     block content
```

Comment: Do you want to run the script from inline javascript, or from an external file?

Comment: I am able to run js client-side from an external file by using script(src="/path/to/script.js") but am unable to get inline js to work

Comment: Turned out that by indenting my script. tag one level allowed the inline js to work. If anyone know why this would be I'd love to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any inline scripts can be run like so

```
script.
  if (usingJade)
   console.log('you are awesome')
 else
   console.log('use jade')
```

from [Docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/).

Any external JS file can be loaded like so:

```
script(src="/path/to/script.js")
```

Also, you may want to be sure that you're actually using your layout file.  Jade recommends doing something like this:

```
extends ./layout.jade
```

Where you have a path to the file and have the extension attached.  Though the extension may be optional because you specify the jade engine in `app.js`.

Let me know this helps!

Comment: My layout is loading although I will take best practice on board, thanks! I am able to run js client-side from an external file, however, inline is still not working when using if (usingJade). I dont understand?!?

Comment: Well that's odd!  Can you see the script tag when you inspect the HTML you receive?  Are you getting any JS errors in the console?

Comment: There is no script tag being included in the html. No errors in node console or in the browser.

Comment: I had my script. tag indented at the same level as 'block content', moving it one tab out fixed this...not sure why?

Comment: Ah, I'm happy I could help.  I was about to comment back saying it worked in my environment, so it must be something else!