# How to add google AdSense on my node js project

Tags: node.js, express, pug, adsense

I created a website using node js, express, and jade.
I wanted to put some ads on my website using google adsense.

I have created an Google AdSense account and was asked to put a line of code between the head tags(1).

Because I am using jade for my websited, I changed the code into the a jade-friendly code(2).

However, Google Adsense says it can not find the code in my site.

I am confident that there are no mis-spelling/wrong syntax in both my URL and my script.

Please help!

(1). `<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234123412341234" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>`

(2). script(data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234123412341234" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js")

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Node.JS or Express, only with pug. Anyway - check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29976085/3107689

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use script. in JADE templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975610/how-to-use-script-in-jade-templates)

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you just needed to add commas in between the attributes.

Also, probably not a good idea to share your keys in a public forum.

```
script(data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234123412341234", async, src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js")
```